# How to make nested list from list where values are counts of list items Python

Tags: python

I have one list `l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`, is there a fast / pythonic way to created nested list from `l1` list that looks like this:

```
l2 = [['a',1], ['b',2], ['c', 3], ['d',4], ['e',5]]
```

So second value in sublist should be count value.

I was thinking about `for loop`, but im sure that there is a better solution then this:

```
l2 = []

c = 0
for item in l1:
   c += 1
   l2.append([item, c])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension like so and enumerate, starting at 1:

```
l2 = [[x, i] for i, x in enumerate(l1, start=1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) with a list comprehension:

```
l2 = [[val, i] for i, val in enumerate(l1, start=1)]
#Output:
[['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3], ['d', 4], ['e', 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use enumerate:

```
l2 = [[i,j+1] for j,i in enumerate(l1)]
print(l2)
```

output:

```
[['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3], ['d', 4], ['e', 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the three similar answers already posted, you could use `zip()` and  `range()`:

```
data = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
# py2
result = zip(data, xrange(1, len(data) + 1)
# py3
result = list(zip(data, xrange(1, len(data) + 1))
```

Compared with `enumerate()`, this seems to be a bit faster on py2, and a bit slower on py3

NB: you'll notice that in both cases, the result is not a list of lists but a list of tuples. That's not accidental. Semantically, a list is an homogenous position-independant collection - items in the list should be interchangeable (for the code using them at least) and their position in the list should not define the "semantic" of the items (the item's meaning should not change based on it's position in the list) -, while tuples are heterogenous position-dependant data structures - elements of a tuple are not interchangeable and the exact meaning of each item is defined by it's position. Actually, a tuple is a position-based equivalent of a dict, where indices are used instead of keys.

Answer (score 0):

The best pythonic way to do this is through the enumerate() function. It returns a number/value pair for each element in an iterable. You can set the starting value as a second argument to enumerate:

```
l1_enum = enumerate(l1, 1)
```

Then you just reverse the places to get the element first (enumerate returns (count, element) pairs as tuples):

```
l2 = [list(reversed(pair)) for pair in l1_enum]
```

The list() cast is needed as reversed() returns an iterator, and not a list.

Comment: While the OP indeed use the term 'count', what he obviously want (from his example) is the (1-based) index.

Comment: I realized that as I posted the answer. I've edited it to match the actual question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Using a list comprehension (to reverse the  `item, index` pair) is simpler and probably faster...